# Fructose from the Seminal Vesicles

Tags: sex, sugar, bacteria, reproduction, fungal-infection

I have been contemplating how chronic gut-originating infestations such as Candida overgrowth and Small Intestinal Bacteria Overgrowth (SIBO) link to symptoms in the male reproductive system, i.e., prostatitis, low libido, and poor orgasm quality (low ejaculation volume, low level of pleasure, etc.) (ED is *not* one of the symptoms in the picture).

I recently learned that the seminal vesicles produce fructose on a routine basis.  Obviously if bacteria or fungus are entering the reproductive system through large or small intestinal permeability, and are coming into contact with fructose, one would expect them to feed on it and become even harder to kill.  Is this a sensible hypothesis?  What is the intended purpose of the fructose produced by the seminal vesicles?  If the reproductive system was "starved" of this fructose due to bacteria and/or fungus competing for it, what symptoms would be expected (analogous to how, i.e., malnutrition can occur in SIBO patients due to bacteria stealing nutrients)?

Comment: Are you asking what would happen if you developed a bacterial infection of the reproductive organs?

Comment: Bacterias use the glucose present in your blood. They may not even care about fructose.